# Iterating through string array

Tags: c

i have array of strings.

```
char strings[][30]={"word1","word2",......,""};
```

Iterated over them but at the end i got message **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Tried with following code :

```
for(int i=0;strings[i] != "";i++){printing items...}
```

I think the problem is with `!= ""`  but why isn't it working?

Comment: Answers below are correct. You could also change to null as the last string. thats a common technique . Then you terminate on `strings[i] != null` or just `strings[i]`

Comment: @pm100: the array doesn't store pointers, does it?

Comment: `strings[i]` will never `== ""`, because you're comparing the address of strings in working memory to the address of a string constant in read-only memory. If you're looking for strings to be "equal" in the sense of having the same character sequence, you need to use `strcmp()`, not `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strcmp` to compare strings in C. `==` or `!=` doesn't work for strings in C.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare strings that way.  Arrays in most contexts decay to a pointer to the first element, and strings are arrays of characters.  What you're actually doing is comparing the address of `strings[i]` with the address of the string literal `""`.  These are always unequal, so the comparison will always be true.

As a result, you iterate past the end of the array.  Reading past the end of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as a crash.

You need to use `strcmp` to compare strings.  It returns 0 if the strings match.

```
for(int i=0;strcmp(strings[i],"") != 0;i++)
```

Comment: .: The comparison is always `true`?

Comment: In this specific case you can also use `strings[i][0]` as the condition since the first character in `""` is the null terminator (which has a value of `0`).

Answer (score 0):

The contents of character arrays cannot be compared with `==` or `!=` in C. Both `string[i]` and `""` would decay to a pointer, and the respective pointer values will never be equal. Hence, you exceed array bounds and yield undefined behaviour then.

But you could easily check if the first character of a string is the string terminating character or not:

```
char strings[][30]={"word1","word2",""};

for(int i=0;strings[i][0] != '\0';i++)
{ ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this array initializer

```
char strings[][30]={"word1","word2",......,""};
```

the last element of the array in fact is initialized the following way

```
char strings[][30]={"word1","word2",......, { '\0' ) };
```

In this condition

```
strings[i] != "";
```

there are compared two pointers: the first one is pointer to the first character of the character array `string[i]` and the second one is pointer to the first character of the string literal `""`.

For clarity the condition can be equivalently rewritten the following way

```
&strings[i][0] != &""[0];
```

It is evident that the pointers are unequal each other because the character array occupies its own extent of memory. The array does not overlap the static memory occupied by the string literal.

To make the loop correct you can rewrite the condition the following way

```
for(int i=0; *strings[i]; i++){printing items...}
```

or

```
for(int i=0; strings[i][0] != '\0' ;i++){printing items...}
```

Take into account that if you'll even write for example the following condition

```
"" == ""
```

it is not necessary it will yield `true` because depending on compiler options the compiler can store these two string literals separately and not as one string literal. In this case the addresses of the string literals will be different.